# Convert excel percentile formula in sql

Tags: sql

```
  =PERCENTILE((C2:C11080,E2:E11080,G2:G11080),73%)
```

The above formula is excel percentile formula, which i want to convert into SQL and 11080 is the count of that column.

Please if anybody can help me it would be very helpful.

Comment: What is the definition of the table you wish to apply this to? what column**s** are you using?

Comment: **Hex ID,Airtel,AirtelCount,Jio,JioCount,VodaIdea,Count VodaIdea** these are the column names

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: I am using phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1):

I believe `percentile_cont()` is what you're looking for:

```
declare @data table
(
    [value] int
)

insert into @data
values 
    (225),(251),(266),(340),(347),(460),(521),(769),(1425),(2911),(3018)    

select distinct
    percentile_cont(0.73) within group (order by [value]) over ()
from @data
```

Result from this query matches what I get in Excel for the same values:

[image: Excel]
[image: SQL]

More information on `percentile_cont` from Microsoft [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/percentile-cont-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).