# Percentile in sql server 2008 r2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, percentile

I am very new to query so please help me out with this query. 
I want percentile of three columns in `SQL Server 2008 R2`, If in this it is not possible in SQL Server 2008 R2 then `phpMyAdmin` is an another option

The following is an example of columns:

```
A   J   C
5   1   1
1   5   4
3   22  10
3   1   3
5   103 117
3   20  156
4   3   1
37  2   9
1   2   18
```

Please help me it will be very thankful.

Comment: Can you add expected results. Not sure what you are asking

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27850364/61305

Comment: Phpmyadmin is for MySQL (and MariaDB); for you can't use it with SQL Server.

Comment: How is this different from your [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52929933/convert-excel-percentile-formula-in-sql)?

Comment: I need percentile of 3 columns together

Comment: In previous post they have given answer which is for 1 column and it is also not working for me

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your table name is table1 you can use the following sql query with analytic functions where A,J,C are the column names of the table.

`select A/sA*100.0 PA,J/sJ*100.0 PJ,C/sC*100.0 PC from  ( select A,sum(A) over () sA,J,sum(J) over() sJ,C,sum (C) over() sC from table1 )`

Comment: ER_PARSE_ERROR (1064) - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '() sA,J,sum(J) over() sJ,C,sum (C) over() sC from   sample )' at line 3 . i am getting this error in mysql phpmyadmin

Comment: Yes, you kindly asked about a problem for SQL SERVER 2008 r2 and you tested with Mysql Server that does not support window functions.

Comment: i tried on sqlserver 2008 r2 but it is not working there also.